# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) on apt-get upgrade

Tags: raspbian, apt, terminal, update, dpkg

I'm using Raspberry Pi 1 model B without GUI and when I try to upgrade software using `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get the following error:

```
Segmentation fault
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 139
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Segmentation fault
dpkg : error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-rpi.gpio_0.6.2~jessie-1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 139
Segmentation fault
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 139
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-rpi.gpio_0.6.2~jessie-1_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried many "solutions" for this problem but none of them have worked, so I guess asking here may help.

I tried `sudo aptitude upgrade` and I get

```
dpkg: error processing package python-rpi.gpio (--configure):
package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
reinstall it before attempting configuration
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
python-rpi.gpio
```

Comment: try sudo apt-get purge python-rpi.gpio the reinstall with sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-rpi,gpio

Comment: A segmentation fault is a memory access violation. You can try a filesystem check - see http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/42022/8697 Unfortunately these are rarely recoverable, you should go back to a known backup.

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]
the user @Milliways say it was a memory access violation. so i tried using a different sd card (i was using an 8gb class 6 and now i'm using an 16gb class 10) and everything went perfect now i can upgrade and install anything

Comment: Please can you mark this answer as correct if it solved your problem